# How to add date picker in ionic 5

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to add a date picker like [Angular Material Date picker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) into an Ionic 5 application. I don't want to use the native [ion-datetime](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime) component because it does not show the entire calendar and does not support other calendars like Jalali, etc.

Comment: use "<input type='date' onchange="selectDate($event)" />

Answer (score 0):

it's same as an angular.

**follow the steps.**

```
1. ng add @angular/material (simply walk through the terminal and all time press y)

2. import following in module.ts

   import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
   import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
```

3. write the code in html

   ```
   <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
     <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
     <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
     <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
     <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
   </mat-form-field>
   ```

Comment: In order to use Angular material, you should add all the CSS theme files and install many requirements which leads to an increase in the size of js files.

Comment: you can use [angular-mydatepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-mydatepicker)